# Trying to use Group to get Max on two columns with Linq

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I've been translating my programs to use Entity Framework 6 for the last two days. For the most part I have it down with simple CRUD operations. Today I hit a snag. I'm trying to convert;

```
    Using SQLSERVER_Connection As New SqlConnection(GlobalVariables.SQLServer_Login_Details)
        Using SQLCommand As New SqlCommand
            Dim Command As New Text.StringBuilder
            Command.AppendLine("SELECT TOP(1) EarningsYear AS PayYear, Max(EarningsAmt) AS EarnAmt, Max(Hours) AS HRS")
            Command.AppendLine("FROM interview_payroll")
            Command.AppendLine("GROUP BY CLIENTCODE, EarningsYear, SSN")
            Command.AppendLine("HAVING CLIENTCODE = @CLIENTCODE AND SSN = @SSN ORDER BY EarningsYear DESC;")
            SQLCommand.CommandText = Command.ToString
            SQLCommand.Connection = SQLSERVER_Connection
            SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@CLIENTCODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sCLIENTCODE
            SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@SSN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSSN.Text
            SQLSERVER_Connection.Open()
            Using Reader As SqlDataReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
                While Reader.Read()
                    If Not IsDBNull(Reader("PayYear")) Then txtPayrollSourceDate.Text = CStr(Reader("PayYear"))
                    If Not IsDBNull(Reader("EarnAmt")) Then txtPayrollErnAmt.Text = CStr(Reader("EarnAmt"))
                    If Not IsDBNull(Reader("HRS")) Then txtPayrollHRS.Text = CStr(Reader("HRS"))
                End While
            End Using
            SQLSERVER_Connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

into Linq.

I've got as far as;

```
    Using DB As New wotcEntities

        Dim Reader = From payroll In DB.interview_payroll
                     Where payroll.CONTROL = CONTROL And payroll.CLIENTCODE = sCLIENTCODE
                     Group payroll By payroll.CLIENTCODE, payroll.EarningsYear, payroll.SSN Into GPayroll = Group



    End Using
```

But I just can't seem to jump the hurdle to get the MAX in EarningsAmt and Hours. I have this program called 'LINQ - Sample Queries' but it shows a MAX query as;

```
Public Sub LinqToSqlCount08()
    Dim latestHire = Aggregate emp In db.Employees _
                     Into Max(emp.HireDate)

    Console.WriteLine(latestHire)
End Sub
```

Which isn't going to work if I want to include PayYear.

I could just grab each part as separate queries, but that doesn't feel right.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the application "LINQPad". It can really help with writing queries and seeing the results immediately.

I created a table similar to what I could gather from your query, and was able to write this query which I believe does what you're asking for.

The "select" is where the Max aggregates are applied.

```
from payroll In Interview_payrolls
where payroll.CLIENTCODE = sClientCode
group payroll By payroll.CLIENTCODE, payroll.EarningsYear, payroll.SSN Into GPayroll = group
select PayYear = EarningsYear, EarnAmt = GPayroll.Max(Function(p) p.EarningsAmt), HRS = GPayroll.Max(Function(p) p.Hours)
```

Hope it works for you.